# How do you change parent's state from child when the state is a database table?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a parent component, a class App.js and has a state, say accounts = []. I fetch the data from a Postgres table in the componentDidMount() function.

Then render follows:

```
render() {
  const { accounts } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <section className="section">
        <Form ... />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Table accountsList={accounts} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see I have two child components, a class Form and a functional component Table. I have managed to actually print on screen the Postgres table using the Table component with the current accounts state.

The problem: Form accepts account fields. So, onSubmit, it creates and post request and passes a json account that creates using the form inputs. The post request will take a while to update Postgres table.

What I want: When the onSubmit from child component Form, actually completes, that is not the code but actually the Postgres table update completes, the accounts state will change. So I will have to change parent's state from a child. I guess I will have to fetch again, maybe this time inside Form.js.

Then if I am corrent, the Table will hot reload and the data on screen will be up to date.

The function (inside Form) triggered onSubmit is the following

```
onFormSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch("/accounts", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      rName: this.state.rName,
      rPass: this.state.rPass,
    }),
  });
};
```

Any ideas? Please, note that I don't want to just append accounts list. I actually want to fetch again because by the time the post request completes, other users may have delete or also update the Postgres table.

Comment: Did you consider making a second request to GET the new state after the POST completes?

Comment: Extract fetching logic from didMount handler to a separate method. Then call it once again after POST request is done `onFormSubmit = (event) => {fetch().then(() => this.loadAccounts())}`

Comment: Of course. But 1) this GET (fetch) has to be done on child i think, which means that i have to change parents state in child. I dont know how to do this. 2) There must be a way so to trigger this GET request and the post request completes. How do i do that?

Comment: "1) this GET (fetch) has to be done on child i think," well, no. Usually you should lift the state to the common parent of table and form. "2) There must be a way so to trigger this GET request" well, yes, fetch returns a promise so you could use `.then(soFunctionToRunOnSuccessResolutionIEWhenRequestSucceeded)`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function to update the `accounts` in the `Form` component from the `App` component. When you invoke the `onFormSubmit` function you can also invoke that function and pass the new account.
But there is one moment: `fetch` returns [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you should to process it. I mean you should add new account to `account` only in `then`.

So function to add new account may look like:

```
/* App component */

const addAccount = account => {
  this.setState({ accounts: [...this.state.account, account],
};
```

And your `onFormSubmit` function will look like:

```
/* Form component */

onFormSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch("/accounts", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      rName: this.state.rName,
      rPass: this.state.rPass,
    }),
  })
    .then(() => addAccount({ rName, rPass }))
    .catch(() => console.log("error"));
};
```

I don't know which properties your accounts have so I pass to `addAccount` function the `rName` and `rPass` but you should pass right data.